# Compiler error "Pointer being freed was not allocated" only while using a foreach loop of custom objects in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, c++17, copy-constructor

I have an assignment where I build my own my string class.  I made several MYString objects and put them in a vector. When I access the vector through subscript operator, I have no issue.  But when I traverse through the vector using foreach loop, then I get a weird error ""Pointer being freed was not allocated"

1. Did I mess up my copy constructor?
2. Is my destructor and clear() function messed up?

header file is as follows:

```
    class MYString{
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const MYString&);
        friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, MYString&);
        private:
            static const int INITIAL_CAP = 20;
            char* str;
            static int getLength(const char*);
            int cap;  //capacity of the char array, in multiples of 20
            int end;  // location of the null terminator
            int compareTo(const MYString& rhs);
            void clear();  // to manually free memory
            static int requiredCap(int end);
        
        public:
            MYString();
            MYString(const MYString& mystr);
            MYString(const char*);
            ~MYString();
    
            MYString& operator=(const MYString& rhs);
            char& operator[](int index);
            const char& operator[](int index) const;
    
            int length() const;
            int capacity() const;
            const char* c_str();
    
            MYString operator+(const MYString& rhs);
    
            int operator==(const MYString& rhs);
            int operator>(const MYString& rhs);
            int operator<(const MYString& rhs);
    };

Here is some relevant function defintions
```

```
MYString::MYString(const MYString& rhs){
    *this = rhs;
}

MYString& MYString::operator=(const MYString& rhs){
    if (this == &rhs){
        return *this;
    }

    clear();
    cap = rhs.cap;
    end = rhs.end;
    str = new char[cap];

    for (int i = 0; i < end; i++){
        str[i] = rhs[i];
    }

    str[end] = '\0';
    return *this;
}

MYString::~MYString(){
    clear();
}

void MYString::clear(){
    cap = 0;
    end = 0;
    delete[] str;
    str = nullptr;
}
```

```
The main method is as follows:
```

```
#include "MYString.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    ifstream input;
    input.open("file.txt");
    if (input.fail()){
        cout << "File error" << endl;
    }


    MYString s;

    vector<MYString> v;
    int count = 0;
    v.push_back(MYString());
    int index = 0;
    while (input >> s){
        if (count == 2){
            v.push_back(MYString());
            count = 0;
            index++;
        }
        if (count < 2){
        v[index] = v[index] + s;
        count++;
        }
    }
    
    for (MYString& str : v){
        cout << str << endl;
    }
```

Comment: You put 4 strings into the vector, but try to read 5 at `cout << v[4] << endl;`.

Comment: Your copy constructor calls `clear()` which will call `delete[]` on an uninitialized `str` (since it is not defaulted to `nullptr`)

Comment: I fixed up my main method.  The main point if I use foreach loop and access the value by reference, it works; but if I access by value, then I get a strange error.  What is the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Serious problem with your constructor:

```
MYString::MYString(const MYString& rhs){
    *this = rhs;
}
```

Inside the body of your object, your data is not initialized, but you dereference this and *assign* to it.  The data members contain garbage, including the pointer.  In the assignment operator, you call clear, which calls `delete[]` on this garbage pointer.  This is undefined behavior.

Implementing a constructor in terms of assignment is always wrong.  Assignment is for *replacing state of an initialized object with new state*, while constructors *provide initial state to uninitialized members*.  The object's lifetime has not even started UNTIL the constructor completes.  Calling functions on an object whose life has not officially started is undefined behavior.

Your copy constructor needs to allocate memory and copy the data into it, similar to what you did in your assignment operator, but not cleaning up the old state first.  Also, consider using strcpy instead of a loop to copy bytes.  It will be faster.